# Write test cases for model using rspec with 100% coverage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, rubocop-rspec

Hi I am working on RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and Rails 5. I have a forgot_password model and i am writting test cases for it using rspec.
I have two methods in model as follows:-

```
class ForgotPassword < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :create_token

  def self.create_record(user)
    forgot_password = create!(expiry: Time.zone.now + ENV['VALIDITY_PERIOD'].to_i.hours)
    send_forgot_password_email user, forgot_password
    forgot_password
  end

  def self.send_forgot_password_email(user, forgot_password)
    return if Rails.env == 'test'
    Mailjet::Send.create(from_email:  ENV['MIALJET_DEFAULT_FROM'],
                         from_name: ENV['MIALJET_FROM_NAME'],
                         to: user.email,
                         subject: 'Forgot Password',
                         text_part: forgot_password.token)
  end

  private

  def create_token
    self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
  end
end
```

First method creates a record of forgot_password and another method send an email using mailjet.
My spec is as follows:-

```
spec/models/forgot_password_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ForgotPassword, type: :model do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user)

  describe '#create_record' do
    it 'do not raise_error' do
      expect { ForgotPassword.create_record(user) }.not_to raise_error
    end

    it 'increment the count of ForgotPassword' do
      expect { ForgotPassword.create_record(user) }.to change(ForgotPassword, :count)
        .from(0).to(1)
    end

    it 'return instance of ForgotPassword' do
      expect(ForgotPassword.create_record(user)).to be_instance_of(ForgotPassword)
    end

    it 'return nil when env is test' do
      expect(ForgotPassword.send_forgot_password_email(user,ForgotPassword.last)).to eq(nil)
    end
  end
end
```

When i run `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake` i got `Coverage (99.58%) is below the expected minimum coverage (100.00%)` Please help me to write the missing case. when i remove `return if Rails.env == 'test'` this line from send_forgot_password_email method it covers 100%. Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use a line like `return if Rails.env == 'test'` sparingly. I would probably remove it entirely here because you want your tests to be as close as possible to the real thing. Rails has a feature in test mode where it doesn't actually send emails out. Instead, it collects them in an array for you so you can test the email's content. If you remove that line, you should be good to go.

Comment: Your app code should not be aware of the Rails environnement. i.e. not have anything testing stuff like `Rails.env`. What you should have is, depending on your environnement, injections/rewrites/mocking. If you want to test for example a Geo-locating service (like Google), your test suite should not actually perform the call through the API but instead *mock* the response only for the test environnement.

Comment: By the way, you can read up on mailer testing here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers. The documentation talks about `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` which you can use to see if your mailers are doing their job.

Comment: Another advice, aiming for 100% coverage is not the best idea IMO. It will take a lot of time to reach this. There are several discussions online about this. Aiming for 85-90% seems to be the norm instead.

Comment: Agreed, don't put environment related things in your code. That belongs in your spec helper, most likely. Definitely mock your external calls, or use something like VCR (love it!) to make a real response, and use that as your mock. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @emptywalls

Comment: But someone told me you're not allowed to have interaction with third party with unit test so please mock interaction with mailjet. Please let me know how should i modify my test.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MailJet through `ActionMailer`](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-gem#send-emails-with-actionmailer). Make sure `ActionMailer` doesn't send out emails in the test env:

```rb
# config/environments/test.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

and use [`enqueue_email` RSpec matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/4-0/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-mail-matcher).

Also, don't do this:

```rb
user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
```

outside of the example scope. See [this work-in-progress `rubocop-rspec` cop](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-rspec/pull/1016/files#diff-bf740f029cdc7a98eb0d03a2cd0fd19372609b7af4978e5e400e5ba2708e5f88R77) for explanation.
If your intent is to reuse the record in several examples, take a look at [`let_it_be` from `test-prof`](https://github.com/test-prof/test-prof/blob/master/docs/recipes/let_it_be.md).